# Scrollbar doesn't update on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar, jquery-masonry

I'm using the jQuery Masonry plugin on my page. I've set it up so that when a box is clicked, a popup dialog is displayed with the contents of the box.

I've created a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FS34t/175/).

before the popup is shown, there's a scrollbar on the page because all the boxes don't fit there. When one of the boxes is clicked, I append the content into the popup and show it. I hide all the other boxes but the scrollbar doesn't update to reflect the popup i.e. the content in the popup is less than the viewing area but the scrollbar still stays for boxes.

If you've understood what I meant, could you help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Masonry is applying a fixed height to the containing `#grid` element, which is why the scroll height stays the same even when all the contents are hidden.  If you move the popup element outside of the containing `#grid` element, and show / hide the grid on click, the scroll height will update correctly.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Udz3J/1/)

The important bits:

```
<div class="reader">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id="grid">
    <!-- content -->
</div>

<script>
    $('.box').click(function() {
        $('.reader').show();
        $('#grid').hide();
    });

    $('.reader #close').click(function() {
        $('.reader').hide();
        $('#grid').show();
    });
</script>
```